# Jython + JavaFx FXML ID access

Tags: java, javafx, jython, fxml

I would like to know how to access FXML ID (fx:id) variables in Jython. I know that these can be accessed as follows in Java:

`@FXML private Canvas canvas`

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is any pre-packaged way to do this right now, but I would love to be proven wrong.  The use of Java annotations inside of Jython is among the aims of [jythontools/clamp](https://github.com/jythontools/clamp), but it seems they have not gotten around to that yet.  Apparently, there is [some work](https://github.com/jythontools/clamp#supporting-java-annotations) to do.